# How to pre-render pages in static HTML for an Angular app?

Tags: angular

**WHAT:** I am building a website with Angular and I’d like to deploy it on a purely static server (such as Amazon S3). I need to pre-render all HTML pages for the site before deployment and I’m not sure how to proceed.

**HOW:** My current idea is to have some crawler read a file like `sitemap.xml` to retrieve a list of all the site’s URLs, then send requests for these URLs to a server where Node.js is installed and an instance of my Angular (Universal) app is running.

**QUESTION:** Does it sound like the proper way to do it? Am I missing an important step? Are there any libraries or npm packages that could help in this task?

Surprisingly, I couldn’t find any documentation about pre-rendering for Angular (only RE-rendering). I’ve also looked at static site generators for inspiration, but they all use a bunch of static files as their starting point (NOT a list of URLs). Also, I don't want to use a third-party service like prerender.io.

Comment: Perhaps https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: Hi Günter. Like I wrote, the app running on the server would indeed be a Universal app. But my question really is about how to generate the static HTML files, not about how to run an Angular app server-side.

Comment: I assumed there is some way to persist the generated output. I didn't have a closer look at Universal yet. If this doesn't do it, then I guess it will be difficult. Why do you actually think you need to pre-render everything. You can deploy the build output of an Angular2 application to any server just fine.

Comment: You're right. But I'm doing out of curiosity and also because I like the upsides of hosting on a purely static server (better performance, simpler configuration...). It's all about the [JAMstack](https://jamstack.org/) ;-). Since the site I'm building would have 600-700 pages, pre-rendering looks like a good option. The doc at https://universal.angular.io/overview/ does mention pre-rendering but it only says "Generate static HTML with build tool" and doesn't elaborate.

Comment: @AngularFrance, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I haven't. I ended up using a purely client-side (Angular) solution with no pre-rendering and no Angular Universal. Google manages to index the site so that's good enough for now. Once Angular Universal has matured a little I might give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just completed similar task using Angular 4. Site is hosted using Github pages and has no backend. Feel free to use it as example: [repo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-site) and commit which implements pre-rendering: [0d81d28](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-site/commit/0d81d28b732d3e6a4be4c2e1db8e9a5b416ea437)

I had to implement following changes:

- Create server app module and update browser app module as described in angular universal guide
- Implement pre-renderer script. Pre-renderer inspects router configuration and retrieve available app routes.
- For each URL pre-render generates html file using `renderModuleFactory` from `@angular/platform-server` module and saves generated html in appropriate location.
- As Bhargav mentioned static files server won't support any URL. So if you need to have URL like `/community/overview` then html should be saved into `/community/overview/index.html`. Angular matrix params wan't work :( . I had to move matrix params into URL route e.g. instead of `/docs;doc=overview.html` use `/docs/overview.html`
- In order to fix annoying flickering after page loading, add `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` into router configuration: `RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: '', ...}], { initialNavigation: 'enabled' })`. I still have no idea what initialNavigation is and why it helps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FWIW I created an Angular documentation issue asking them to flesh out their guide on this front. I referenced your answer. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23024

Comment: And one year after writing this answer, the author switched to [GatsbyJs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), a React-based static site generator... @Alexander, could you please shed some light on why Angular Universal was that bad?

Comment: I never could find a good solution for this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16051#issuecomment-328241418 . This issue pretty much defeats pre-rendering benefits if page url does not have an extension

Comment: @AlexanderMatyushentsev your pre-rendering commit link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the similar task in Angular 13. First change your angular.json file as

```
  "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "my-app:build:build",
        "serverTarget": "my-app:server:server",
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ],
        "guessRoutes": false
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
          "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
        },
        "staging": {
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build:staging",
          "serverTarget": "my-app:server:staging"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    }
```

I have passed specific routes to the prerender command. If you choose this option, make sure to turn off the guessRoutes option.

In package.json in scripts add build command like this:

```
"build:prod": "ng build --configuration production --aot && ng run my-app:prerender:production --no-guess-routes --routes /",
"build:staging": "ng build --configuration staging --aot && ng run my-app:prerender:staging --no-guess-routes --routes / ",
```

As SSR is done at runtime it will take some time to render the HTML page on the fly but Pre-rendering directly serve the pre-rendered HTML page on request. So basically it'll improve the performance even better than SSR.